# Ghost API not adding post body

Tags: ghost-blog

Having an issue where when using the following payload with a `post` request on `https://localhost:2368/ghost/api/v0.1/posts` the body of the post is not loaded into ghost blog.

```
{
  title: 'some title',
  html: '<p>some html</p>',
  plaintext: 'some plaintext'
}
```

After the request, only the title is loaded into ghost blog.

Using Ghost v2.13.1

Would be helpful discover field(s) that should be used for the body of a post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@mattcameron Ghost uses `mobiledoc` ([spec](https://github.com/bustle/mobiledoc-kit/blob/master/MOBILEDOC.md)) - the `html` and `plaintext` fields are generated from that and can't be set separately.

The v0.1 API is private and not documented as it wasn't designed for use outside of the admin area, if you can I suggest you wait a little while for the v2 Admin API which will be released soon along with SDKs to make it easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin for help. With your suggestion found this https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost-SDK/tree/master/packages/html-to-mobiledoc

Now my payload looks something like this

`{title: 'some title',mobiledoc: JSON.stringify(converter.toMobiledoc('<p>some html</p>'))}`